# Change a specific link from text with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm very new to Greasemonkey, so please be understanding. Here is my problem :

I'm currently doing some changes to a web game to make it more usable on a laptop to have a bigger fullscreen without getting rid of any functions. I've basically done everything by myself, but now there's something that I'm not able to do. I want to change the URL (clickable through some text) to my specific URL. I've figured that I can change the href value from the previous url (/maps) to my url (/search). But I'm not able to implement it into my script, as it doesn't work the same as the previous things I changed on the website.

Can anyone help? I think this is relatively easy, I just can't find anything on it, maybe I'm googling the wrong terms.

Comment: You need to provide more information, like the code you want to change or a link to the game or... that will make it easier to help you

Comment: The element is called <a class="sidebar-anchor__anchor" href="/maps">. I want to permanently change /maps to /search. Here is the link to the website just in case.

https://www.geoguessr.com

You will be able to find the "Browse Maps" category in the sidebar, this is what I'm trying to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the additional information in the comments, this should do

```
document.querySelector("a[href='/maps']").href = "/search";
```

while there's only one of these elements at the time of this answer. If that changes, you can use `querySelectorAll` instead and iterate the results then.